# Python-for returning a generator of sequences

Tags: python, generator

I have to generate a function which takes any number of sequences and return a list of tuples.
I have tried writing code for generating tuples one by one through generators from the list by using the following code:

```
>>> gen1 = [(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(4)]
>>> gen1
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> iter1 = iter(gen1)
>>> iter1.next()
>>> def gen3():
...     yield iter1.next()
...
>>> next(gen3())
```

Which is giving the tuples. But I need to apply the same code in the following function which contains many sequences of parameters:

```
def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs):
```

How can i use the above mentioned code in this function??

Comment: By the way, you've used the word "phyton" in every single question you've asked and never added a [python] tag yourself. The language is called "Python", not "Phyton", and if you don't tag correctly you're going to have a lot of trouble getting help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're reinventing this functionality? It already exists in `itertools.izip`.

Comment: This looks more like itertools.product than itertools.izip

Comment: only his example ... `generator_zip` ... sounds just like izip to me ...

Answer (score 2):

I think [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you are looking for

```
import itertools

print list(itertools.product(range(3), range(4)))

>> [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), 
>> (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]

print list(itertools.product(range(2), range(3), range(4)))

>> [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), 
>> (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), 
>> (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), 
>> (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Note that itertools functions always return generators

Comment: I cannot use the itertools functions but i can use the izip implementation .But, can't get it.@Icfseth

Comment: it's not very hard actually. A x B x C = (A x B) x C = AB x C = ABC. By using an iterative approach you can join the first 2 lists into one single list until and keep doing that until you have one single list

Comment: I think iZip is implemented in C for speed, you won't probably find its python code.